# Optimal query to find both (x,y) and (y,x) records

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given that I have a table `messages`

```
sender_id    recipient_id
==========   =============
1            2
1            3
2            1
```

Whats the most optimal query to get records in which one value is 1 and the other 2, i.e for the above example dataset, it should return both (1,2) and (2,1). Currently I am using something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE 1 IN (sender_id, recipient_id) AND 2 IN (sender_id, recipient_id)
```

but this appears to be sub-optimal. Is there a better way to it?

**EDIT**

- I do not need to filter out repetitions
- I have compound-indexed sender_id and recipient_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sender can't also be the recipient:

```
select * from messages
where sender_id in (1, 2)
and recipient_id in (1, 2)
```

If it's possible to be both, add another filter:

```
select * from messages
where sender_id in (1, 2)
and recipient_id in (1, 2)
and sender_id != recipient_id
```

Comment: That seems like the fastest, it uses indexes if available and lazy evaluation if possible.

Comment: @Victory: Your conclusion is valid for basic indexes (and that's about all you can do in certain other RDBMS). In Postgres, the query in combination with a functional index like a_horse_with_no_name displays is *faster*. It can make do with a single index scan.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter This will use a single index scan and will perform just fine. Unless the need is **super** critical for speed, the hassle and overhead of the extra functional index is a waste of everyone's time. I doubt the speed difference would be noticeable anyway. IMHO simple solutions are always to be favoured over complex ones.

Comment: @Bohemian: No it doesn't. I tested before I posted and got either two bitmap index scans (with two single-column indexes) or a bitmap index scan and a bitmap heap scan (with a muliticolumn index), where a_horse's solution only needs a single index scan and is about twice as fast. I am also using a similar solution myself for the same reason. Since either query is very fast, you are right about the hassle - unless you need to *optimize* performance. And the Q asks for the `most optimal query`. Hence my comment.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter OK, that's a surprise - I would have expected it to use just one index and filter the results on the other condition. Regarding "most optimal', that can mean different things to different people. Meanings include "least code", "most elegant", "most scaleable", "most flexible", and of course "squeezing every last drop of performance out of it, regardless of legibility or maintainability".

Comment: Well, you are right about that, too. The requirement is not all clear.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward approach seems to me to be to use `IN`:

```
select *
from messages
where (sender_id, recipient_id) in ((1, 2), (2, 1));
```

Testing on SQL Fiddle shows that it is sometimes faster than Bohemian's answer, and sometimes slower, depending on the data present. But for readability, I think this is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sender_id, recipient_id
from messages
where (least(sender_id, recipient_id), greatest(sender_id, recipient_id)) = (1,2);
```

This can be supported by an expression based index if needed:

```
create index from_to_index on messages 
  ( least(sender_id, recipient_id), greatest(sender_id, recipient_id) );
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's faster than the presented alternatives (for some overhead cost maintaining an additional index).